# libor rate - local martingale

Tags: martingale, numerairechange

I am a newbie for Libor rates and all these questions...

Let be : $L(t,\delta)$ the Libor rate and $L_{t}(T,\delta)$ the forward Libor rate.
Let's define :
$Lb(T,\delta):=1+\delta L(T,\delta)=1/B(T,T+\delta)$ and
$Lb_{t}(T,\delta):=1+\delta L_{t}(T,\delta)=B(t,T)/B(t,T+\delta)$.
The question is to prove that under the forward measure of maturity $T+\delta$  that both $Lb_{t}(T,\delta)$ and $L_{t}(T,\delta)$ are local martingales.
I began to define the forward measure of maturity $T+\delta$ (under which the numeraire is $B(T,T+\delta)$ ) :$Q^{T+\delta}$ but it's a lot of calculus. So how can we solve this ? Do we have to start from the model $dB(t,T)/B(t,T)=r_{t}dt+\Gamma (t,T)dW_{t}$ in order to define $dQ(t,T+\delta)=...dQ$ ?

Comment: actually if I write : $Lbis_{t}(T,\delta)=B(t,T)/B(t,T+\delta)=E_{Q^{T+\delta}}[B(T+ \delta,T)|F_{t}]=E_{Q^{T+ \delta}}[B(t,T)/B(T+\delta,T+\delta)|F_{t}]$ I think that answers my question isn't it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, under the $T+\delta$-forward measure, the price of any tradable asset relative to the bond price $B(t, T+\delta)$ is a martingale. Since
\begin{align*}
Lb_t(T, \delta) = \frac{B(t, T)}{B(t, T+\delta)},
\end{align*}
it is a martingale by definition. Regarding $L_t(T, \delta)$, since
\begin{align*}
L_t(T, \delta) = \frac{1}{\delta}\left(\frac{B(t, T)}{B(t, T+\delta)} -1 \right)
\end{align*}
is a linear combination of martingales, it is also a martingale.

Comment: many thanks ! Does my solution work if i write that :
$B(t,T)/B(t,T+ \delta):=E_{Q^{T+ \delta}}[B(T+ \delta,T)|F_{t}]=E_{Q^{T+ \delta}}[B(T+ \delta,T)/B(T+ \delta,T+ \delta)|F_{t}]$ (the first equality is for me the definition for $Q^{T + \delta}$

Comment: There is no such thing as $B(T+\delta, T)$, unless you defined it differently.

Comment: True I wanted to make a paralell with $F_{t}(S,T):=S_{t}/B(t,T)=E_{Q^{T}}[S_{T}/B(T,T)|F_{t}]$ so that we have something like $B(t,T)/B(t,T+h)=E_{Q^{T+h}}[???/B(T+h,T+h)|F_{t}]$

Comment: You can have $B(t, T)/B(t, T+h) = E_{Q^{T+h}}(B(T, T)/B(T, T+h) \mid \mathscr{F}_t)$, for $t \le T$.

Comment: all right that's what I was going to write ! Thanks !